# Найти в массиве максимальное кол-во повторяющихся элементов подряд

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти в массиве максимальное кол-во повторяющихся подряд элементов и вывести какой элемент повторяется и его первый индекс.

Например дан такой массив (в массиве могут быть не только строки но и цифры):

`const arr = ['re','tres','tred','test','test','test','yt','ttt','ttt','test','test'];`

Где, строка 'test' повторяется подряд 3 раза. Вывод в консоль должен быть примерно такой объект:

```
object = {name = 'test',count: 3, index: 3}
```

Моя попытка:

```
const arr = ['re','tres','tred','test','test','test','yt','ttt','ttt','test','test'];
let s = [];
let count = 0;
arr.forEach((item,index,array) => {
  if(item == array[index +1]) {
    s.push({item,index,count});
    count++;
  }
})
```

Comment: А что, если пройти по массиву в цикле, сравнивая элемент с предыдущим?

Comment: А где ваши попытки решить данную задачу? Что вы пробовали? Что не получается?

Comment: Добавил мои попытки

Comment: @Jon, у вас заголовок вопрос не совпадает с постановкой задачи в самом вопросе. решение для задачи со словом `подряд` не совпадает с решением без слова `подряд`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = ['re', 'tres', 'tred', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'yt', 'ttt', 'ttt', 'test', 'test'];

console.log( getLongestChain(arr) );


function getLongestChain(arr) {
  let main = {}; // Главный претендент на самый длинный
  let temp = {}; // Временное хранилище текущей цепочки

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === temp.name) { // Повторяющийся элемент
      temp.count++;
    } else { // Наткнулись на новый элемент
      if (temp.count > (main.count || 0)) { // Надо ли переписать основной объект
        main = cloneObject(temp);
      }
      // Создаем новый временный объект, с данными уже текущего элемента.
      temp = ChainData(arr[i], i);
    }
  }
  return main;
}

function ChainData(name, index) {
  return {
    name: name,
    count: 1,
    index: index,
  }
}

function cloneObject(obj) {
  let x = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    x[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Буду разбираться

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = [
    're','tres','tred','test','test','test',
    'yt','ttt','ttt','test','test','a','a','a'
];
const series = arr.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
        const last_element = acc[acc.length - 1];
        if (last_element && last_element[0] === x) {
            last_element[1]++;
        } else {
            acc.push([x, 1]);
        }
        return acc;
    },
    []
);
const max = series.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0];
console.log(max);
```

**Подробнее**

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - применяет функцию к каждому элементу массива, возвращая одно результирующее значение

[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - сортирует элементы массива и возвращает отсортированный массив.

Сортировка не обязательно [устойчива](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) по этому результатом *для массива из моего решения* может быть и `['test', 3]`, и `['a', 3]` (с оговоркой об устойчивости сортировки с современных браузерах). Но в задаче не сказано, что нужна именно первая серия.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Буду разбираться